# Compiling Node.js with OpenSSL support

Tags: node.js, ssl

Hi guys trying to do a remote install of Node.js, following this set of instructions [here](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/How-do-I-install-Node-2906459.S.66037932)

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-v0.4.10.tar.gz 
tar -zxvf node-v0.4.10.tar.gz 
cd node-v0.x.x 
./configure --prefix=~/node 
make 
make test 
make install
```

this should set me up with a nodejs install under `~/node` however, during the `./configure --prefix=~/node` I encounter the this in the dependency requirement:

```
node-v0.4.10]$ ./configure --prefix=~/node
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : not found 
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : not found 
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : not found 
/opt/server/node-v0.4.10/wscript:341: error: Could not autodetect OpenSSL support. Make sure OpenSSL development packages are installed. Use configure --without-ssl to disable this message.
[tomcat@test.dev node-v0.4.10]$ make
Project not configured (run 'waf configure' first)
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

I have checked that open ssl is on the box:

```
node-v0.4.10]$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

 ~]$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)
```

Not sure what other dependencies their are, been looking for a config file

Comment: You really should start with a recent version of node, v0.4 is ancient. As of this writing, v0.10.32 is the latest stable version of node.

Comment: Any reason you can't get one of the binaries? http://nodejs.org/download/  TLS is already in there.  You just need to require it in your code.

Comment: I am unsure of the unix install process for the newer versions ./configure returns ./configure
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory from within ~/NodeJS/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/ and ~/NodeJS/node-v0.10.32-linux-x64/bin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is already packaged for the most popular [distributions](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager).

If my guess is right, and you're using CentOS 6 or similar, the following command should work fine:

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```